# find specific string pattern in text using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, string, expression, multiple-matches

I need to find the regular expression to use as an argument in `string.matches`.
I have a text of strings separated by space `" "` and i want to find what type of Number is it. First of all i need to check pattern like this: `"[number] E [number] & [number]"`. `&` is a symbol in the string, so is `E`.

```
// so *word* is a string tested       
if (word.matches("\d++ E *\d++ & \d++")) *something like that*
```

For example `"1001Ε101&2"` is true and `"0114&2"` is false.

So I need the regular expression in `word.matches(" *answer* ");`

It's a project in lexical analysis. I must not use ready lexers.

Comment: `Pattern.matches("\\d++ *E *\\d++ *& *\\d++", answer);`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is almost right. Simply use it this way:

```
Pattern.matches("\\d++ *E *\\d++ *& *\\d++", word);
```

with `word` the string to check.

Don't forget to use a double `\` in your regex string where you would put a simple `\`.

Comment: thanks! but it doesnt work... i think we are too close. Should i declare something above that? Create a new pattern object? or compile the regular expression? i have seen some examples and i am really confused..

Comment: you don't need to declare  a pattern object if you use `matches(String, String)` as this method is `static`. Compilation is needed for performance if your app often uses this pattern. Once compiled, you can use it calling `yourPattern.matcher(word).match()`

Comment: what is your `Ε` char? That's not an ascii `E` (0x45)

Comment: ok i understand that . But it doesnt work.. its giving false to the exact example above

Comment: @Ionnis Papakwasta try this one: `Pattern.matches("\\d++ *Ε *\\d++ *& *\\d++", word);` It use the same `E`char as your example (that is not the 0x45 ascii char)

Comment: E is "E"  a char    0x45 ascii         yes

Comment: OK!! thanks..worked.. just copied from regular expression to string declaration to be sure that is the same.. dont understand why this happened anyway!

Comment: One thing more sir ;) ! how can i add symbol "+" to the expression. for example i want it to be in the beggining e.g +1001Ε101&2 true

Comment: of course i tried "*+* \\d++ *E *\\d++ *& *\\d++"   and many other like versions. but i get syntax exception

Comment: `+`` is a quantity qualifier in a regex. To use the character `+`simply escape it: `\\+` then add the quantity qualifier ( `?` for 0 or once, `+` for once or more).  To test for plus and minus symbol: `[\+\-]?`. More informations on Pattern [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Vote Up...no reputation!

Comment: sorry enter doesnt change line : "[\\+\\-]? *[A-F0-9]++} *E *\\+\\-]{1}? *[A-F0-9]++ *& *16"    i want it to recognise A71BE+12&16 for example. but it doesnt work because E is recognised by [A-F0-9]  but i want necessarily an E before + , -